# Display document in android java from byte array with out downloading the file

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to display a document from byte array with out downloading it to the mobile local storage or external storage, is it possible to do that in android

byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(returnBase64(), 0);

returnBase64 will return the string received form service;

Comment: Yes of course. But how did you get that document in that array?

Comment: got it from the web api to display in the app

Comment: In your answer i expected you to name that byte array. You did not clear up anything.

Comment: i have updated the code in the answer , how i am getting the array.

Comment: I think there is a pdf viewer component for your app who does that. You cannot use an external pdf viewer unless you implement a content provider for that byte array.

Comment: thanks this gave some idea, but i am looking for all the file types not only for pdf.Is there any inbuilt android feature to do this , or should we proceed with custom component or a third party library

Comment: Im amazed that you ask for a component that could display all kinds of documents. Be realistic!

Comment: The content provider approach you can use for all kind of files of course.

Comment: Thanks i will try this, is there any place in local storage where user cant search the file directly , this helps me to secure the file where user cant access it

Comment: In getFilesDir() and on an Android 11 device in getExternalFilesDIr() too.

Comment: getFilesDIr(); works but what i am trying to do is to launch the downloaded file in pdf reader. But user should not search and get the file , if we store in getFilesDir other apps cant access it

Comment: That is not needed either as you have to use a FileProvider to serve your file to other apps.

Comment: @Girijesh Have you implemented any solution for the above-mentioned problem because I have to implement the same kind of requirement?